# Equivalent assertions for a quadratic number field

Tags: analysis, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$. Why are the following two assertions equivalent?

- $\mathcal O_K$ is factorial
- $\mathcal O_K$ is a principal ideal domain

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain). Now there is the following fact.

*A Dedekind domain $A$ is UFD if and only if it is PID.*

Let me give you a sketch of proof.

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is clear. The implication $\Rightarrow$ follows from the fact that in UFD every prime ideal of height $1$ is principal. Now in a Dedekind domain by definition every prime ideal is either zero or of height one. Thus if $A$ is both a Dedekind domain and UFD, then every prime ideal in $A$ is principal. Moreover, every ideal in a Dedekind domain can be uniquely decomposed onto a product of prime ideals. Thus every ideal in $A$ can be uniquely decomposed onto a product of principal ideals. Hence every ideal in $A$ is principal, because it is a product of principal ideals.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a simpler proof for the quadratic case, even if it is ad hoc.